# Is $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Is $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$?

I tried the homomorphism $\phi(a+bi)=\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\ 0 & a
\end{pmatrix}$.
The problem is $\phi$ is homomorphism but not into the center $Z(M_2(\mathbb{R}))$.

Comment: The map $\phi$ does have image contained in the center, but it's not a ring homomorphism (it doesn't preserve multiplication)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. An algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ is a ring equipped with a homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}$ to the center of the ring. But the center of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

There *are* subrings of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, but none of them is contained in the center for the same reason: there is no ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, your map is *not* a ring homomorphism. For instance $\phi(-1)=\phi(i^2)\ne\phi(i)^2$.

Comment: There's lots more than one such subring isomorphic to $\Bbb C$....

Comment: Lol, did I say you said there was only one? Is this conversation recursively defined?

Comment: @DavidWheeler Your use of ellipses strongly suggested you were framing your comment as an objection to egreg's answer and not as a tangential, standalone remark.

Comment: Not an objection, a comment. There's nothing wrong with his answer, I *like* it.

Comment: @DavidWheeler I modified my answer taking your comment into account. You can probably remove the obsolete comments.

Answer (score 3):

No. A homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb C\to M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ must be injective, so its image is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ and it's contained in $\mathbb R$ (the center of $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$), impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Prove (if you haven't already) that $Z(M_2(\Bbb R)) = \Bbb R I_n$ (where $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix).

Then show $\Bbb C \not\cong \Bbb R \cong \Bbb R I_n$, showing such an algebra is impossible.

(since $\Bbb C$ is a field, any such ring-homomorphism $\eta:\Bbb C \to Z(M_n(\Bbb R))$ must be injective, or $0$).

Comment: Actually one has to prove more: $\mathbb R$ doesn't contain a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Good point, I should edit my answer, but I'm feeling awfully lazy, today.